# Ionic 4 Native Offline data storage and sync when network comes back even if app is closed

Tags: cordova, ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app, cordova-plugin-advanced-http

I use Ionic-4 Native with angular and Cordova to make a hybrid mobile app.

I want to make an App that take some data from the user while being offline or online and then sends them to a service for storage with an http post action.

I can check if i have internet. And store the jsons into a local database.
My problem is that the user can open the app, insert the information and then close the app.
So how i can check later if the internet is back up to send/post the data?

Should i make a background task to check every x amount of time and if we have internet to send the data then? How i can shedule a background task?

Is there a way the andorid system to handle the POST when it gets internet on its own?

Is there another way?